# How to give raspberry pi 0 with apache 2 an domain name?

Tags: pi-zero, apache-httpd

I made an webserver with apach 2 on my raspberry pi 0.
But they did not explain how to link your paid domain name to your webserver.
Can someone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have a fixed IP address in your home (or where ever you host the Pi) for this server?

If you do, then you talk to your ISP about putting your `ip-name` on their webservers. You also need to add the routing inside your home, but that's very router specific.

If you don't have a fixed address, you'll need to pay to join a DDNS (Dynamic Domain Name Service) company that follow your `ip-address` changes and make sure that your name and address are linked.

In either case, you'll need to set the hostname and domain name on the Pi so that everything is consistent. You can do this through `raspi-config` which handles all the files. I know you need to modify `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`, but it's easier to do this with `raspi-config`.

Comment: Your answer has a lot of faulty facts. ISP and ip-name ??? Dont bother with that and what is ip-name? Pay for DDNS, there is a lot of free DDS services. And the question is "how to link your paid domain name to your webserver".